# Load specific files in a folder to different sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, powerquery

I was trying to convert a VBA macro code to power query but looks like m stuck now.
I have a folder which can have upto 4 files. 3 with .dat extention & 1 with .txt extension. What I want to achieve is to load all the files having .dat extension to different worksheets. I tried two approaches.

**Approach one** - Everything in a single query

1) Get all files in folder

```
GetFiles = Folder.Files("FolderPath"),
```

2) Filter files with .dat extension

```
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(GetFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat")),
```

3) Add a column that combines filePath & fileName

```
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilterFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name]),
```

4) Check which of the 3 files are available

```
    Tab1 = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], "Tab1")),
    Tab2 = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], "Tab2")),
    Tab3 = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], "Tab3")),

    HasTab1 = Table.RowCount(Tab1),
    Tab1Content = if HasTab1 > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab1[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else "",

    HasTab2 = Table.RowCount(Tab2),
    Tab2Content = if HasTab2 > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab2[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else "",

    HasTab3 = Table.RowCount(Tab3),
    Tab3Content = if HasTab3 > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab3[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else "",
```

For this approach i have the file content loaded as query step but i still don't know how to output them to different sheets.

**Approach two** - modular, separate files for separate things

1) Query GetFiles

```
AllFiles = Folder.Files(FolderPath)
```

2) Query FilterFiles

```
AllFiles = GetFiles,
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(AllFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat"))
```

3) Query BuildFilePath

```
FilteredFiles = FilterFiles,
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilteredFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name])
```

4) Query FileExists

```
FileExists = (TabName, FileTable) =>
    let
        TabRow = Table.SelectRows(FileTable, each Text.Contains([Name], TabName)),
        RowCount = Table.RowCount(TabRow),
        HasFile = if RowCount > 0 then TabRow[FilePath]{0} else "false"
in
    HasFile
```

5) Query LoadTab1

```
Source = BuildFilePath,
FilePath = FileExists("Tab1", BuildFilePath),
LoadFile = if FilePath <> "false" then Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath), null, "~") else ""
```

In this step I am getting error

> Formula.Firewall: Query 'LoadTab1' (step 'LoadFile') references
>   other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source.
>   Please rebuild this data combination.

Also I just want to load the Files and not the intermediate tables

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe* this...

Start with the part of your query that pulls the folder info as its own query. (If you set it up to load to as connection only it won't create a spreadsheet.) I named it *GetFolderInfo*:

```
let
GetFiles = Folder.Files("FolderPath"),
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(GetFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat")),
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilterFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name])
in
BuildFilePath
```

(Replace *"FolderPath"* in the query above with your actual folder path, ending with \ and all in quotes. Example: "C:\mypath\".)

Then create a function that references the GetFolderInfo query. Like in my earlier answer, I called this one *GetTab*:

```
let
Source = (TabName) => 
let
Tab = Table.SelectRows(GetFolderInfo, each Text.Contains([Name], TabName)),
HasTab = Table.RowCount(Tab),
TabContent = Tab{[#"Folder Path"="FolderPath",Name=TabName&".dat"]}[Content],
ToCSV = if HasTab > 0 then Csv.Document(TabContent) else ""
in
ToCSV
in
Source
```

(Replace *"FolderPath"* in the function above with your actual folder path, ending with \ and all in quotes. Example: "C:\mypath\". *DO NOT change #"Folder Path"*.)

Then invoke the GetTab function from three separate queries like in my earlier answer.

```
let
TabName = Function.Invoke(GetTab,{"Tab1"})
in
TabName

let
TabName = Function.Invoke(GetTab,{"Tab2"})
in
TabName

let
TabName = Function.Invoke(GetTab,{"Tab3"})
in
TabName
```

Comment: @Nikhil, In case you tried this and it didn't work, I realized there was an error because I didn't adjust the code to account for the fact I had used a parameter while testing. This version doesn't use a parameter. I just corrected the error and added some parentheticals to make sure you know to replace "FolderPath" in two places: once in the initial query and once in the function.

Comment: Hello Marc, i just tried it and it works good. Just made a small change to the GetTab query. Instead of using `Tab{[#"Folder Path"="FolderPath",Name=TabName&".dat"]}[Content]` I used `Tab{0}[Content]` otherwise i had to find a way of propagating the FolderPath to this query as well.

Comment: That *is* better. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Each query loads a separate sheet, so you need three queries:

```
let
Source = "",
GetFiles = Folder.Files("FolderPath"),
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(GetFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat")),
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilterFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name]),
Tab1 = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], "Tab1")),
HasTab1 = Table.RowCount(Tab1),
Tab1Content = if HasTab1 > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab1[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else ""
in
Tab1Content

let
Source = "",
GetFiles = Folder.Files("FolderPath"),
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(GetFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat")),
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilterFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name]),
Tab2 = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], "Tab2")),
HasTab2 = Table.RowCount(Tab2),
Tab2Content = if HasTab2 > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab2[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else ""
in
Tab2Content

let
Source = "",
GetFiles = Folder.Files("FolderPath"),
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(GetFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat")),
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilterFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name]),
Tab3 = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], "Tab3")),
HasTab3 = Table.RowCount(Tab3),
Tab3Content = if HasTab3 > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab3[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else ""
in
Tab3Content
```

When you *Close & Load* the Query Editor, it will create 3 spreadsheets...one for each tab file.

Comment: Yaa, I know I can do this but there is a repetition of the first 3 lines in all queries. Which I wanted to avoid by making it modular.

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe you might want to try a function. Something like this function, which I named *GetTab*:

```
let
Source = (TabName) => 
let
GetFiles = Folder.Files("FolderPath"),
FilterFiles = Table.SelectRows(GetFiles, each ([Extension] = ".dat")),
BuildFilePath = Table.AddColumn(FilterFiles, "FilePath", each [Folder Path] & [Name]),
Tab = Table.SelectRows(BuildFilePath , each Text.Contains([Name], TabName)),
HasTab = Table.RowCount(Tab),
TabContent = if HasTab > 0 then Csv.Document(File.Contents(Tab[FilePath]{0}), null, "~") else ""
in
TabContent
in
Source
```

Which I then invoke from three other separate queries:

```
let
TabName = Function.Invoke(GetTab,{"Tab1"})
in
TabName

let
TabName = Function.Invoke(GetTab,{"Tab2"})
in
TabName

let
TabName = Function.Invoke(GetTab,{"Tab3"})
in
TabName
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, this is more efficient but in this approach we will read/access the folder/dir again and again in each query. I was thinking of finding a way to get folder/dir data once into table and then use that table every where. Do u think that is possible.